# Find correct kernel version to build module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I want to checkout kernel sources to build a kernel module. However when I want to `insmod` the module I get a "Invalid module format" error. The kernel versions appaerently do not match.
`uname -r` results in version `3.0.35-gd0fc8d0`.
I am on a i.Mx6 Processor and have to checkout a branch from here: https://github.com/boundarydevices/linux-imx6

But I can't seem to find the exact matching kernel version?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a kernel module against the specific kernel version so that they are compatible with each other.

you should be able to know the kernel version with which a module is built using modinfo command.

#modinfo kernel_mod.ko

look at vermagic field here.

Comment: Thank you! That gives me `3.0.35-gb0b02db-dirty SMP preempt mod_unload modversions ARMv7` 
Where does `gb0b02db` come from? I need `gd0fc8d0`

Comment: You can try force insmod : like insmod -f mod.ko

Comment: If force insmod is not working,  You may need to rebuild and install your kernel. Basically you need to disable CONFIG_MODVERSIONS while building the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a hurry, you can try to change Vermagic of kernel module in order to insert the module.

Reference: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/how-to-change-the-vermagic-of-a-module-728387/
Or
just google, "Change vermagic of kernel module".

By the way, you should keep in mind that this method can cause a problem.